# Style particular text inside input : REACT ( normal css/ tailwind any)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Is there any possible way inside react , Inside an input field when user type particular word that only word change its color.

Example: Input value is "Step1: abc // Step:2 efg // Step3: hij "
Is it possible to color or highlight "//" inside input field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the placeholder text of any input or textarea using the placeholder modifier in tailwindcss.

```
  <input class="placeholder:italic placeholder:text-red-600 placeholder:text-lg  text-green-700" placeholder="Search for anything..." type="text" name="search"/>
```